# insert into single-columned table using t-sql

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with a single INT type column that's auto incrementing.  is there a way to insert new values in that column using t-sql.

If i have a table like the following:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu](
[MNUId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MNUName] [nvarchar](250))
```

I can insert like so:

```
 INSERT INTO [Menu] (MNUName) VALUES ('menu name');
```

The above will automatically increment MNUId because its auto-increment is on.

but what if there is no MNUName column and I only have the MNUId colmn?  What's the t-sql statement to insert into such a table?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Menu DEFAULT VALUES
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) docs, `DEFAULT VALUES` section.